# Android 12 SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission not applied in new process

Tags: android, process, alarmmanager, android-permissions, android-12

Hy guys

## Situation

I have been updated MyApp to target Android 12 and ran into some odd behavior with the new SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission.

I have following problem with the new introduced permission

In my **AndroidManifest.xml** I declared the permission as following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.myfirm.myapp">
          .... more permissions
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
          <application>
          ....
          </application>

           <service
            android:name="com.myfirm..services.KernelStartedService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":KernelStartedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myfirm.service.kernel.api.ANDROID_KERNEL_SERVICE_BINDING_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

</manifest>
```

As you can see in the declaration the value of the process attributes starts with a colon (:)
this means a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process.

Before Starting or binding this service I invoke a test if the permission is given with this helper function:

```
private fun canExactAlarmsBeScheduled(): Boolean {
        val alarmManager = this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()
        } else {
            true // below API it can always be scheduled
        }
    }
```

In the onStart Method of the first Activity I then do a test if the permission is givien, if not, I provoke showing a dialog to the user that he needs to give this permission to my app:

```
override fun onStart() {

            // non relevant code here
            if (canExactAlarmsBeScheduled()) {
                initApplication() // here the service will be started/ bound
            } else {
                // start System Settings to enable alarms, coming back to Myapp will
                // provoke an onStart again
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.bootstrap_need_permission_to_schedule_alarms,getString(R.string.app_name)))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_ok)) { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                        intent =  Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM).apply {
                            data = Uri.fromParts(PACKAGE_SCHEME, packageName, null)
                            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        }
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    .show()
            }
        }
}
```

This above is working well for the MyApp.

## Problem:

I do ensure that only if the Permission of Scheduling exact alarms is given, the above mentioned Service "KernelStartedService" will be started in a new process.
**The already granted permission is not taken by the new process in which the service is running in**

If later on in classes that are running in this dedicated Process are testing  **alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()**. Then it **ALWAYS** is returning **false**!

## Question:

How can I achieve to take over the permission SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM also for the process called ":KernelStartedService"?
The other permissions like...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

...are all respected also for this new process. Why is the declaration

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

not respected in the separate process ":KernelStartedService"

As far as I see, this is a bug of Android 12  (API31 -App) when it creates the Process not applying this permission to the new process.

## Expected behavior

I would expect that if the permissions are granted for the app-process, and afterwards I start a service in separate process, that all permissions would be applied to the new created process.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

using below two lines in manifest solved  the problem for android 13.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```